# First and Second Highest elements from array without using System defined function >sort it >remove duplicate values >print 1st & 2nd highest values

Tags: java, arrays

public class SecondHieghestValueSolution {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = {1,2,2,3,3,4,5,4,6,4,3,6,5,3};
    int x, n = arr.length;
```

//      Sorting

```
    for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j > 0; j--) {
            if (arr[j] < arr[j - 1]) {
                x = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j - 1];
                arr[j - 1] = x;
            }
         }
     }
```

//      Removing Duplicate

```
    int[] arr2 = new int[n];
    int j = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<n -1; i++) {
        if (arr[i] != arr[i+1]){  
            arr2[j++] = arr[i];  
        }  
     }  
    arr2[j++] = arr[n-1];
```

//      Changing original array

```
    for (int i=0; i<j; i++){  
        arr[i] = arr2[i];  
    }  
    
    int[] temp = new int[j];
    for(int z = 0; z<j ; z++ ) {
        temp[z] = arr[z];
    }
```

//        printing first and Second largest no. in array

```
    System.out.println("The First Largest No. in the array is " + temp[temp.length -1]);
    System.out.println("The Seconf Largest No. in the array is " + arr[temp.length -2]);
}
```

}

Comment: Do you have a question?  Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  And dumping a bunch of code here with no explanation is not one of the ways.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = {1,2,2,3,3,4,5,4,6,4,3,6,5,3};
    int x, n = arr.length;
    for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j > 0; j--) {
            if (arr[j] < arr[j - 1]) {
                x = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j - 1];
                arr[j - 1] = x;
            }
         }
     }


    int[] arr2 = new int[n];
    int j = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<n -1; i++) {
        if (arr[i] != arr[i+1]){  
            arr2[j++] = arr[i];  
        }  
     }  
    arr2[j++] = arr[n-1];     


    for (int i=0; i<j; i++){  
        arr[i] = arr2[i];  
    }  
    
    int[] temp = new int[j];
    for(int z = 0; z<j ; z++ ) {
        temp[z] = arr[z];
    }

    System.out.println("The First Largest No. in the array is " + temp[temp.length -1]);
    System.out.println("The Seconf Largest No. in the array is " + arr[temp.length -2]);
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).